# HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: private array

Tags: c++, arrays, destructor, heap-corruption

So I had to make a programm with a class Point, it takes how many dimensions it has and then I made a funktion in the class that takes so many coordinates, and to do so I had to make a dynamic array since the size isn't fixed.

```
class Punkt
{
private:
    char n;
    int d;
    double* k = new double[d];
public:
    Punkt(int);
    void Name(char);
    void Initialisieren();
    ~Punkt();
};
```

This is where these functions are defined:

```
Punkt::Punkt(int dimension)
{
    d = dimension;
}

void Punkt::Name(char name)
{
    n = name;
}

void Punkt::Initialisieren()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < d; i++) {
        cout << "Geben sie bitte die " << i + 1 << ". Koordinate von " << n << " ein: ";
        cin >> k[i];
        cout << endl;
    }
}

Punkt::~Punkt()
{
    cout << "Destrukt: " << n << endl;
    delete[] k;
}
```

When starting my program I get my message `Destrukt: B`, but the `Destrukt: A` is missing (I first declare A and then B) and it then gives me the error. It also doesn't do any of the couts I tell it to do with some other functions I have made but didn't listed them down. Can someone please help me? I know it has already been asked so many times but mostly those people had problems bcs the made an array of chars and forgot about the last place which contains a zero.

P.S. the programm is written in German, if it should be changed please tell me because I am new in this section.

Comment: Violation of the Rule of Three?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice that you have the following in the class definition:

```
int d;
double* k = new double[d];
```

This will initialize k before the constructor runs to a new array of size d. The problem is that d hasn't been initialized by this point because the constructor hasn't run yet. To fix this, move the initialization into the constructor.

You're also going to need a copy constructor and assignment operator, plus optionally a move constructor and move assignment operator. If you haven't heard of these terms, do a quick Google search online.

Comment: I thought that that might be the problem. Thank you for fixing that part.
Now what confuses me is why I have to use that Rule of Three since I haven't had that in my lectures, but if I have to learn it I will just try to google myself out of this problem. Thank you

Comment: Nooooo. Rule of _Zero_! Make that pointer a `std::vector` and now you don't have to do any manual memory management at all.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I assume this is for a class project, but otherwise, definitely!

Comment: the problem is that we haven't had vectors nor the rule of three in our lectures... I am also really confused after watching some videos about the rule of three since the storage created in the constructor is deleted in the destructor... I do understand vectors after watching some videos and tutorials but still, I dont think I can use them. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: @HeatTheIce As long as you don't (1) try copying one of these structures, (2) pass one of these structures by value into a function, or (3) return one of these objects from a function, you should be able to ignore the rule of three. My recommendation would be to either pick up a good introductory C++ book (I cast my vote for "Accelerated C++"), or just wait until later in the quarter when you might learn about them. The advice we're offering here would be for more experienced programmers, so I wouldn't worry too much about it for now.

Comment: @templatetypedef The thing is that this problem was made so that we can solve it with the knowledge we have now.
Regarding (2): I do have a function in the public section with the prototype: void Addition(Punkt B); As much as I understand from yours this is cousing the error... The function should take a point with it coordinates and then add them to the point with which I am calling it, ie. A.Addition(B), the coordinates from B are being added to those of point A.